# /phpmyadmin not found on ubuntu server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, rstudio

I am attempting to install both RStudio and phpmyadmin on an ubuntu server from AWS.

I have spun up a AWS server using RStudio AMI which works successfully (http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/)

I am now attempting to install phpmyadmin on the server.

I have followed the normal steps to do so (installing each individually):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5 mysql-server php5-mysql

mysql_secure_installation

apt-get -y install phpmyadmin
```

This has installed phpmyadmin correctly. However, whenever I attempt to access the following link:

http://52.56.56.80/phpmyadmin I get the following error:

/phpmyadmin not found

I have included the line: "Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf" in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf as advised in other issues, however this does not fix the issue.

What do I need to do to be able to access phpmyadmin on my browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

add "Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf"

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: I already have that line included, and following that restart I still have the same issue

Comment: It's an AWS server, so it's not hosted on my local machine. The server is hosted at 52.56.56.80